# Short-circuiting template specialization in std::disjunction

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++17, static-assert

**Some Background:**

I'm working on putting together a templated class which, as part of template specialization, deduces a type to use for one of its members. This data member needs to support being streamed over the wire, and I'm trying to keep the system as flexible and extensible as possible (with the goal that new variants of the type can be created by modifying some high-level elements of the specialization logic without getting into the guts of the implementation code). Some of the existing usages specialize this data member to be an enum, and the streaming code supports converting this value back and forth to a 32-bit integer for transmission over the wire.

Because an enum could be defined (either implicitly or explicitly) to be backed by a different type -- most dangerous in the case being a 64-bit value -- I'd like to be able enforce that if the resolved type is an enum, its underlying type must be a 32-bit integer (more generally, I just need to enforce that it's a *maximum* of 32 bits, but I'll be worrying about that complexity once the simpler case is working).

**My Attempted Solution:**

Stitching together some of the tools provided by [type_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits), I came up with the following:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

using TestedType = /* Logic for deducing a type */;
constexpr bool nonEnumOrIntBacked =
    !std::is_enum_v<TestedType>
    || std::is_same_v<std::underlying_type_t<TestedType>, std::int32_t>;
static_assert(nonEnumOrIntBacked,
    "TestedType is an enum backed by something other than a 32-bit integer");
```

However, when I tried to compile this (using Visual Studio 2017 on the latest update), I was met with the error text
`'TestedType': only enumeration type is allowed as an argument to compiler intrinsic type trait '__underlying_type'`. Seeing this, I tried an alternative formulation using [std::disjunction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction), which I believe should short-circuit evaluation of templates if an earlier condition evaluates to true (I've ommitted the `std` qualifiers to make this a bit more readable):

```
disjunction_v<
    negation<is_enum<TestedType>>,
    is_same<underlying_type_t<TestedType>, int32_t>
>;
```

I've also tried wrapping the offending usage of `underlying_type_t` inside an `enable_if` predicated on the type being an enum, but didn't have success with that either.

**My Question**:

Do boolean operators in general (and `std::disjunction` in particular) not short-circuit evaluation of templates? On [the cppreference page for std::disjunction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction), it states the following (emphasis mine):

> **Disjunction is short-circuiting**: if there is a template type argument Bi with bool(Bi::value) != false, then instantiating disjunction::value **does not require the instantiation of Bj::value for j > i**

Reading this, I would have expected the ill-formed nature of `underlying_type_t<TestedType>` for some non-enum type to be irrelevant, since downstream types don't need to be considered once something upstream has been evaluated as true.

If my reading of the spec is incorrect on this point, is there another way to accomplish this check at compile-time, or will I need to add a runtime check to enforce this?

Comment: Immediately after posting this, I realized that I could get the results that I was ultimately after with the condition `!is_enum_v<TestedType> || sizeof(TestedType) <= sizeof(int32_t)`. With this check in hand, I no longer have a pressing need for an answer, but I'm still curious about what I'm missing here and it could be useful for posterity.

Comment: `is_same<underlying_type_t<TestedType>, int32_t>` - You're still eagerly evaluating `underlying_type_t` and only delaying the evaluation of `is_same`. Any solution will require delaying `underlying_type`.

Comment: @chris The answer box is below ;)

Comment: @chris I'm not sure if I can find a way to delay evaluation further. I've tried relying on SFINAE to induce a specialization failure prior to attempting to resolve the ill-formed template (something along the lines of `is_same_v<enable_if_t<is_enum_v<TestedType>, underlying_type_t<TestedType>>, int32_t>`, but I'm still getting the same compilation error that way.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I was testing a solution instead of only pointing out the problem, but I have something now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Template arguments are "evaluated" eagerly just like regular arguments. The part causing problems is `underyling_type_t`, but it's present in full in both versions. You need to delay that part until after you know `TestedType` is an enum type. This is fairly straightforward with constexpr if ([live example](https://godbolt.org/g/GTmHWu)):

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool nonEnumOrIntBackedImpl() {
    if constexpr (std::is_enum_v<T>) {
        return std::is_same_v<std::underlying_type_t<T>, std::int32_t>;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

template<typename T>
constexpr bool nonEnumOrIntBacked = nonEnumOrIntBackedImpl<T>();
```

Prior to C++17, one common method is tag dispatching ([live example](https://godbolt.org/g/mVMNVD)):

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool nonEnumOrIntBackedImpl(std::true_type) {
    return std::is_same<std::underlying_type_t<T>, std::int32_t>{};
}

template<typename T>
constexpr bool nonEnumOrIntBackedImpl(std::false_type) {
    return false;
}

template<typename T>
constexpr bool nonEnumOrIntBacked = nonEnumOrIntBackedImpl<T>(std::is_enum<T>{});
```

Comment: Is this true even in the context of `enable_if` and other SFINAE-based templates? I was under the impression that template parameters wouldn't be specialized for `enable_if` and `conditional` unless the proper branch was taken.

Either way, thank you! This should work quite nicely for what I'm doing.

Comment: @bionicOnion, All the templates themselves can do is delay evaluating what they're given. This comes after evaluating to figure out what to give them. In your example, `std::underlying_type` is always called on `TestedType` to form the `std::is_same` argument. The only thing that can be delayed is whether the `std::is_same` template is instantiated to get its `::value`, but its type (including the `underlying_type_t` evaluation) is already set by that time. It would be possible, for example, to make an `is_same` that calls `::type` on its arguments when `is_same`'s `::value` is obtained.

Comment: That way, you could pass something like `lazy_is_same<underlying_type<TestedType>, identity<int32_t>>` and `underlying_type<TestedType>::type` would only be "called" if `lazy_is_same<...>::value` is "called". Of course that's just one way to skin the cat; you could make different laziness choices.

Answer (score 3):

[chris explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474766/4832499) why the construct failed and gave a solution. But in the spirit of exploiting every single feature of the library, here's how to use the short-circuitry

```
template<typename T, typename I>
struct is_underlying
{
    static constexpr auto value =
        std::is_same_v<std::underlying_type_t<T>, I>;
};

using TestedType = int;
constexpr bool nonEnumOrIntBacked =
    std::disjunction_v<std::negation<std::is_enum<TestedType>>, 
        is_underlying<TestedType, std::int32_t>>;
```

The template needs to be well-formed, but not its `value`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative:

```
template <typename T> struct identity { using type = T; };

bool nonEnumOrIntBacked =
    std::is_same<
         std::conditional_t<
             std::is_enum_v<TestedType>,
             std::underlying_type<TestedType>,
             identity<void>>::type,
         int
    >::value
;
```

with `conditional<cont, type1, type2>::type::type` :) to delay evaluation.